# LDA for statistical test

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I was searching for which statistical test to use when:

- The dependent (target) variable is **discrete**.
- The independent variable is **continuous**.

I stumbled onto this table:

https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/FS1.png

which states that you should use an **LDA** in this case. However I couldn't find any case where someone has used it for something similar and it's unclear to me how this should work. So my question is:

How do you use LDA as a statistical test?

If this doesn't work could you point me out to a statistical test for the case I'm looking for? Other sources I've read conveniently overlook this case...

Comment: Your table is missing, and LDA can be used in such cases, this is a standard method, if you couldn't find any resources then you haven't looked very hard. Also, more so than what your data looks like it is more important what your objective is.

Comment: @user2974951 I fixed the ling for the table. My goal is to check the "correlation" of each feature with the target variable so that I can perform feature selection (dump the features that seem insignificant). If you have a reference I can look at or could just tell me the word phrasing I should use for the query that would give me the result I'd be grateful. I really can't find anything on using LDA as a statistical test, maybe I'm phrasing my question wrongly.

Comment: The question doesn't specify how many predictor variables you have. The answer may be different for one predictor or for several predictors.

Comment: Can you explain what your hypothesis is and what your variables are, please? Random things people find on the internet are not always the right place to start. If you're trying to do variable selection, hypothesis tests would not be my first choice.

Comment: @Pere I wasn't aware of that... Currently I have around 30, but I asked the question in more of a general manner. Do you have any sources I could take a look at, or point me at the right direction? I've read on how LDA works but can't grasp how it can be used for statistical testing. If you have another method on your mind I'd be glad to take a look!

Comment: @Glen_b I wanted to compare the performance of multiple variable selection techniques to maybe see the pros and cons of each. From what I've read there are *filter methods*, *wrapper methods* and *embedded methods*. I've tried the latter two, but the first is what is giving me trouble. I need a way to test the "correlation" (I'm not sure what the right term is with categorical variables) of my input variables with the target one. If you have anything in mind, or could point me in the right direction, I'd be grateful!

Comment: if it's so trivial, can't anyone at least point me in the right direction?